# how to avoid this effect =>Formborder is none ,but still visible while loading

Tags: c#, winforms

I am opening child form in parent form ,and I have set `formborder style` to none ,but while opening child for `I can see its border for fraction of second` ,how do I avoid this ,I tried below code but it doesn't making that effect to disappear ,how do I avoid this effect and load form smoothly ,I tried to assign `form opacity = 0` and set timer for applying `fade-in` effect but that is also not solving my issue ,please guide me in right way

**code I tried to avoid this issue**

```
int originalExStyle = -1;
        bool enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering = true;

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                if (originalExStyle == -1)
                    originalExStyle = base.CreateParams.ExStyle;

                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                if (enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering)
                    cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                else
                    cp.ExStyle = originalExStyle;

                return cp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If these are MDI Children forms, then no, you aren't suppose to change the border style.

Comment: If these are not MDI children, the border shouldn't show, if it is set to border= none;
Maybe you have  time consuming code in form load?

Comment: @LarsTech yes forms are ` MDI Children forms` ,but i don't want border ,that's why i set it to none

Comment: Then don't use MDI.  Make your child forms TopLevel = false and add them to a panel's control collection instead.

Comment: @LarsTech if I do above thing ,than this effect will get resolved? and than what about borders ,shall i keep them to `none` only? `add them to a panel's control collection ` means?

Comment: That's what I was suggesting.  Since you don't want form borders, you are effectively using your child forms as user controls.  I would heed Hans' answer and just get rid of your originalExStyle variable — it looks like it is doing more harm than good.

Comment: do you have many controls on the form? I think you should show your form only when it's loaded.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe there is something special with your project.

Answer (score 2):

LarsTech's comment is the probable core problem, MDI child forms *must* have a sizable border.  It is a requirement that Winforms forgets to enforce, runtime mishaps are various and have no workaround.  Otherwise also the explanation why Opacity doesn't work, it can only work on top-level windows.

The usage of *originalExStyle* is also fundamentally wrong, `base.CreateParams` does **not** always return the same value. It changes when your program assigns certain properties of the form that indirectly affects the ExStyle value.  Including Form.MdiParent, it sets the WS_EX_MDICHILD style flag.  You need to remove it and only use `cp`.  Quacks like a hack for another problem you found, it can't work correctly.  Change it to:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering)
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't got this line `You need to remove it and only use cp` ,Can you please show this in code

Comment: You **must** give MDI child windows a border, end of story.